# I need to automate the testing of installing Chrome and Firefox extensions. Suggestions?

Tags: chrome

We are developing extensions for Firefox and Chrome. We need to test installing, uninstalling and ultimately interacting with this extension in a basic way (it will bring up a dialog to log into an authorization server and allow the user to make a choice from several options).

I have tried getting selenium to do this without luck. It seems to come down to needing a general GUI automation tool to make this happen.

I will also be wanting to do automation in both browsers on Mac and Windows. I would love to be able to write the test once - instead of for each platform and each browser, but I will do what I gotta do.

The only other limit is that the organization wants to use free or open source tools. Ranorex looked good, but they did not like the price.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it with selenium, but you should be able to use http://www.sikuli.org/ which uses image recognition for scripting.

Comment: Its not possible with Selenium, since it only drives the browser content.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible in chrome using selenium (Mac and Win), you need to start chrome with the argument "--load-extension=[extension_path]". I don't see why you couldn't do it through the chrome store either, you just would have to switch windows at some point.

Comment: Nice that you can load extensions during start-up.  But the OP states "(it will bring up a dialog to log into an authorization server and allow the user to make a choice from several options)" this dialog cannot not be processed with Selenium if you ask me.

Comment: You're right, most dialogues cannot be interacted with directly. However you can still send keys which would affect the dialog. For example you could send 'tab' characters to navigate and 'enter' to select. This is a bit hacky, but might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for windows

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

And for Mac the Apple Automator or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485254/equivalent-of-autoit-for-mac-os-x